# Qt, cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'A *' to 'const QObject *'

Tags: c++, qt

I'am new in Qt and when I study slots/signals, I find strange behavior.

If I write following code, it's ok.

```
class A;
class B;

class A : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void signal(B*);
};

class B : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void slot(B*) {};

public:
    void f(A* a) {
        connect(a, SIGNAL(signal(B*)), this, SLOT(slot(B*)));
    }
};
```

But if I exchange definition of class A and class B:

```
class A;
class B;

class B : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void slot(B*) {};

public:
    void f(A* a) {
        connect(a, SIGNAL(signal(B*)), this, SLOT(slot(B*)));
    }
};

class A : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void signal(B*);
};
```

I get an error:

```
main.cpp:30:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'
    connect(a, SIGNAL(signal(B*)), this, SLOT(slot(B*)));
    ^~~~~~~
/Users/Alexander/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobject.h:198:36:
    note: candidate function not viable: 
        cannot convert argument of incomplete type 'A *' to 'const QObject *'
        static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal,
```

Why is it happening?

I use QT 5.3.

Thanks.

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a good idea to get rid of all the cruft to understand what's going on:

```
class QObject {};
class A;

void connect(QObject*) {}

void f(A* a) {
    connect(a);
}

class A : public QObject {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    f(&a);
}
```

This is a simplified version of what you have and experiences the same problem. The problem is that at the point that `connect` is called, `A` has only been forward declared. The compiler does not yet know that `A` inherits from `QObject`. It is only later that you define `A` and specify this. For this to work, the definition of `A` must come before the call to `connect`.